# TypeScript: properties are always undefined when extending abstract class

Tags: typescript, rest, express, mongoose

I'm setting up reusable component classes for my REST API controllers, but I cannot seem to get abstract properties working with TypeScript. I've tried a few different approaches and looked through the TS docs, but I haven't found any real solution. All I've found is that abstract properties are really finicky. I'm hoping someone can point out where I'm going wrong with this...

Here is the error I'm seeing: [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'model')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uQmi.png)

EDIT:

I moved reduced my code to a minimal example and created a GitHub repository: https://github.com/JacobDachenhaus/stackoverflow_05-28-2022_140100

Comment: Did you instantiate a UserController using the new keyword? `const controller = new UserController;` Before passing it into router.

Comment: If you don't want instance members, then you should declare static List<T> and static model.

Comment: I simplified your code into [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and it seems to work as you expect: https://tsplay.dev/NBkakm Can you provide a minimal example that breaks?

Comment: @AlexWayne it's only working as expected when using an object instead of a mongoose model... I went ahead and made a GitHub repo that can be cloned for tinkering.